# issue with dispatch event on android browser

Tags: javascript

I want to trigger events so I created the following function which works fine on chrome but not on my android browser (tested on android 4.2)

```
 function trigger(eventName, myEl){
   if (document.createEvent) {
     var event = new Event(eventName);
     myEl.dispatchEvent(event);
   }else{
     alert('no support'); // not fired
   }
 }
```